# How to calculate difference in days between two dateboxes in GWT?

Tags: java, date, gwt, datebox

I have 1 datebox (datebox1) in my GWT application, which allows users to set the date in past.

Datebox1 is set to following format (not that it probably matters):
datebox1.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat (DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy")));

How do I programatically calculate the difference in days between the date selected in the date box and the current date.

I can't find much on the net and would appreciate a simple example.

Comment: People like Basil Bourque & Jarrod Roberson should know, that not all that works in Java will work in GWT as well. I'd typically do that before going ahead and marking something to be a duplicate of a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
int daysBetween = CalendarUtil.getDaysBetween(myDatePicker.getValue(), currentDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code block will be useful for you

```
    Date selectedDate = DateBox.getDatePicker().getValue();
    Date currentDate= new Date();

    long fromDate = selectedDate.getTime();
    long toDate = currentDate.getTime();

    long diffGap = toDate - fromDate;
    long diffDays = diffGap / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know how to extract date from your textbox, you can use the following function  to get the time difference between any two dates

```
public String getTimeDiff(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
String diff = "";
long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
diff = String.format("%d hour(s) %d min(s)", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)));
return diff;
}
```